# Check the existence of statistic with same columns before creating a statistic on a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create some statistics on a table with different combination of columns. But there may be already some statistic exist with same combination of columns. So, Before creating a statistic with a combination of columns, I want to check if there exists any statistic with same combination of columns. If exist then I will not create the statistic and if not exist then only I will create the statistic.

For example create a table and a statistic on this table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE Gift
(
     Gift_Id INTEGER IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     Person_Id INTEGER,
     Event_Id INTEGER,
     Agent_Id INTEGER,
     Fund_Id INTEGER,
     Amount FLOAT
)

CREATE STATISTICS [Stats1_1_2_3] 
    ON [dbo].[Gift]([Gift_Id], [Person_Id], [Event_Id])
```

So we have a table `Gift` and a statistic with columns Gift_ID, Person_Id and Event_Id.

Now If I create another statistic as following:

```
CREATE STATISTICS [Stats2_1_2_3] 
    ON [dbo].[Gift]([Gift_Id], [Person_Id], [Event_Id])
```

See later statistic is duplicate of first statistic (With same columns).

So, to avoid the duplication, I need to check if there exists any statistic with same columns.

Is there any way to do this?

Please help

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih I have updated the question. Please have a look again....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query will give the name of the statistic (If any exists) with the given combination of the columns.

```
SELECT s.name
FROM sys.stats s inner join
sys.stats_columns sc on s.stats_id = sc.stats_id and s.object_id = sc.object_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.[object_id] = sc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(s.OBJECT_ID) = 'Gift'
and s.stats_id not in 
(
    SELECT distinct s.stats_id 
    FROM sys.stats s inner join
    sys.stats_columns sc on s.stats_id = sc.stats_id and s.object_id = sc.object_id
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.[object_id] = sc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = sc.column_id
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(s.OBJECT_ID) = 'Gift' and c.name not in ('Gift_Id','Person_Id','Event_Id')
)
group by s.name
having count(1)= 3
```

[Updated SQLFiddle for the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5cede/1)

Answer (score 3):

The below query will check the sys.stats,sys.stats_columns and sys.columns table to find all statistics for the given table and get each column for each statistic.
The grouping and counting is to check if one statistic exists that refers to all columns.
Note that the query mentions explicitly the table name, the column names and the number of columns that is being checked.
The updated query also checks if ONLY the columns listed are present (counting = 3) and ALL the columns listed are present (counting3 = 3).  Use for other statistics will involve modifications for the CASE statement and the '3' values in the last WHERE line.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT s.name AS statistics_name,
      count(*) as counting,
      sum(case
          when c.name = 'Gift_Id' then 1
          when c.name = 'Person_Id' then 1
          when c.name = 'Event_Id' then 1
          else 0
      end) as counting3
  FROM sys.stats AS s  
  INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc   
  ON s.object_id = sc.object_id AND s.stats_id = sc.stats_id  
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c   
  ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = sc.column_id  
  WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Gift')
  Group by s.name) T
WHERE T.COUNTING = 3 AND T.COUNTING3 = 3;
```

[Updated SQLFiddle for the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48553/4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this quey will not work for some scenerios...
Suppose we want to create a statistic with 2 columns ('Gift_Id', 'Person_Id') and if we check the existance of a statistic with these columns by above code it detacts that the statistic [Stats2_1_2_3] exist with these columns.

Comment: Good point - I need to include an additional check on the total number of items in the statistics as well.  I will update the above for that (if you don't beat me to it - it should be mostly straight SQL based on the same tables)